# Handling Connections in Spring-Boot-RabbitMQ

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

Hi I am developing Spring-boot-RabbitMQ version 1.6.I am having few queries while developing the application. Read the docs and browsed other stack overflow question but i cannot get few things clear(Might be because of my bad memory).
It would be great if some one answers my questions.

1) Currently i am having 4-Producers and 4-Consumers.Producer may produce millions of messages or events so using a single connection for both producer & consumer will block consumer to consume the messages.So what i would thought is creating separate connections for producer and consumer so that both will not block and will give some performance improvement.Am i correct with this approach?

2) I am using **CachingConnectionFactory** in order to create connection using **SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory**.While making call to this factory whether it will return new connection for us?So if we use **CachingConnectionFactory** do we really need to write a separate connection factories for both Producer & consumer.Please find my below

1)**Configuration class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableRabbit
public class RabbitMqConfiguration{

@Autowired
private CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory;

@Value("${concurrent.consumers}")
public int concurrent_consumers;

@Value("${max.concurrent.consumers}")
public int max_concurrent_consumers;

 @Bean
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory() {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(cachingConnectionFactory);
        factory.setConcurrentConsumers(concurrent_consumers);
        factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(max_concurrent_consumers);
        factory.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
        return factory;
    }

@Bean
public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter()
{
    final Jackson2JsonMessageConverter converter = new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    return converter;
}

}
```

2)**Producer Class**

```
@Configuration
public class TaskProducerConfiguration extends RabbitMqConfiguration {

@Value("${queue1}")
public String queue1;

@Value("${queue2}")
public String queue2;

@Value("${queue3}")
public String queue1;

@Value("${queue4}")
public String queue2;

@Value("${spring.rabbit.exchange}")
public String exchange;

@Autowired
private CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory;

@Primary
@Bean
public RabbitTemplate getQueue1Template()
{
    RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(cachingConnectionFactory);
    template.setRoutingKey(this.queue1);
    template.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
    return template;
}

@Bean
public RabbitTemplate getQueue2Template()
{
    RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(cachingConnectionFactory);
    template.setRoutingKey(this.queue2);
    template.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
    return template;
}

@Bean
public RabbitTemplate getQueue3Template()
{
    RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(cachingConnectionFactory);
    template.setRoutingKey(this.queue3);
    template.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
    return template;
}

@Bean
public RabbitTemplate getQueue4Template()
{
    RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(cachingConnectionFactory);
    template.setRoutingKey(this.queue4);
    template.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
    return template;
}
@Bean(name="queue1Bean")
public Queue queue1()
{
    return new Queue(this.queue1);
}

@Bean(name="queue2Bean")
public Queue queue2()
{
    return new Queue(this.queue2);
}

@Bean(name="queue3Bean")
public Queue queue3()
{
    return new Queue(this.queue3);
}

@Bean(name="queue4Bean")
public Queue queue4()
{
    return new Queue(this.queue4);
}

@Bean
TopicExchange exchange() {
    return new TopicExchange(exchange);
}

@Bean
List<Binding> bindings(Queue queue1Bean,Queue queue2Bean,Queue queue3Bean,Queue queue4Bean, TopicExchange exchange) {
    List<Binding> bindingList = new ArrayList<Binding>();
    bindingList.add(BindingBuilder.bind(queue1Bean).to(exchange).with(this.queue1));
    bindingList.add(BindingBuilder.bind(queue2Bean).to(exchange).with(this.queue2));
    bindingList.add(BindingBuilder.bind(queue3Bean).to(exchange).with(this.queue3));
    bindingList.add(BindingBuilder.bind(queue4Bean).to(exchange).with(this.queue4));
    return bindingList;
}

}
```

**3) Receiver Class(Just Shared one receiver class rest of the 3-receiver classes are one and the same except queue name & routing key).**

```
@Component
public class Queue1Receiver {

@Autowired
private TaskProducer taskProducer;

@Value("${queue1}")
public String queue1;

@RabbitListener(id="queue1",containerFactory="rabbitListenerContainerFactory",queues = "#{queue1Bean}")
public void handleQueue1Message(TaskMessage taskMessage,@Header(AmqpHeaders.CONSUMER_QUEUE) String queue)
{
    System.out.println("Queue::"+queue);
    System.out.println("CustomerId: " + taskMessage.getCustomerID());
    if(taskMessage.isHasQueue2()){
        taskProducer.sendQueue2Message(taskMessage);
    }
    if(taskMessage.isHasQueue3()){
        taskProducer.sendQueue3Message(taskMessage);
    }
    if(taskMessage.isHasQueue4()){
        taskProducer.sendQueue4Message(taskMessage);
    }
}

@Bean
public Queue queue1Bean() {
    // This queue has the following properties:
    // name: my_durable,durable: true,exclusive: false,auto_delete: false
    return new Queue(queue1, true, false, false);
}

}
```

Your help should be appreciable.

Note : Down Voters please register your comment before down voting so that in future i can avoid the mistake.

**Edited based on comments by Gary Russell:
1)RabbitMqConfiguration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableRabbit
public class RabbitMqConfiguration{

@Value("${concurrent.consumers}")
public int concurrent_consumers;

@Value("${max.concurrent.consumers}")
public int max_concurrent_consumers;

 @Bean
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory() {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        factory.setConcurrentConsumers(concurrent_consumers);
        factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(max_concurrent_consumers);
        factory.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
        return factory;
    }

@Bean
public CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory()
{
    CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost");
    connectionFactory.setUsername("guest");
    connectionFactory.setPassword("guest");
    connectionFactory.setCacheMode(CacheMode.CONNECTION);
    return connectionFactory;
}


@Bean
public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter()
{
    final Jackson2JsonMessageConverter converter = new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    return converter;
}


}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> using a single connection for both producer & consumer will block consumer to consume the messages`

What leads you to believe that? A single connection will generally be fine. If you really want separate connections, change the connection factory `cacheMode` to `CONNECTION`.

Comment: @Gray Russell thank you for your reply.Actually producer may produce more than a million messages at a time so in that case single connection is enough?Also while reading some blogs they specified handle separate connection for producers & consumers , that's i posted the question here.

Comment: what actually cacheMode=CONNECTION will do? Now i modified my code.Is it fine now?

    @Bean
    public CachingConnectionFactory consumerConnectionFactory()
    {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost");
        connectionFactory.setUsername("guest");
        connectionFactory.setPassword("guest");
        connectionFactory.setCacheMode(CacheMode.CONNECTION);
        return connectionFactory;
    }

Comment: In Spring-boot Application.properties have the following properties configured
spring.rabbitmq.cache.connection.mode=CHANNEL 
spring.rabbitmq.cache.channel.size= 50 
spring.rabbitmq.cache.channel.checkout-timeout= 1000
concurrent.consumers=3
max.concurrent.consumers=10

Is it looks good?

Comment: One connection is generally enough. Don't try to put code/config in comments - it's unreadable - it's better to edit your question instead. `CacheMode.CONNECTION` means each user will use a different connection.

Comment: I modified the RabbitMQConfiguration file based on your comments.Please find the edited section under your name in the question.
Also when the connection will be closed? it is automatically handled by @RabitTemplate or do we need to handle?

Comment: The connections are never closed (until the factory is destroyed) unless the cache size is exceeded, in which case they are closed immediately. You need to be sure that the cache size is at least large enough for the number of concurrent publishers to avoid opening/closing connections rapidly.

Comment: Got it.In spring-boot application via following property spring.rabbitmq.cache.channel.size= 100  we can set the connection cache size right?

Comment: No; that's channels cached per connection. It's `...cache.connection.size` (available in boot 1.4 only). But since you are declaring the connection factory as a `@Bean`, boot won't configure one.

Comment: Since i declared my bean as @Bean it won't take "Cache.connection.size" properties too right?Instead of properties is it possible to do it via code to set "cache.connection,size"?

Comment: Correct - to use properties you need to use the auto-configured bean; if you declare the bean yourself, you are responsible for setting the properties.

Comment: I write my own connection factory just to set CacheMode : Connection.Otherwise i would have use auto-configured one.Do you know how to set those properties manually? Or in-order to use auto-configured connection factory how we can set CacheMode : Connection?

Comment: With boot 1.4 you can use `...cache.connection.mode=CONNECTION`. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/amqp/RabbitAutoConfiguration.java#L133

Comment: Russel I am using Spring-Boot 1.3.3. Is it possible to set cache properties manually?

Comment: For older boots you have to wire it up yourself using your own properties.

Comment: One more thing "convertAndSend" is asynchronous and "convertSendAndReceive" is synchronous?

Comment: That is correct, but there is a new `AsyncRabbitTemplate` in 1.6 that has async send and receive.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. Let me check the new documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use connection pooling in the same case keeping the pool size appropriate may solve the problem.As suggested in the above answer both producer and consumer are using the same connection so pooling might help you out instead.